# How will China's Xuntian space telescope use its Terahertz capability? THz Spectroscopy? Imaging? Something else?

Tags: observational-astronomy, radio-astronomy, space-telescope, radio-telescope, csst

1. [An Update on the Chinese Space Station Telescope Project](https://www.issibern.ch/teams/weakgravlense/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/H.-Zhan.pdf) Hu Zhan, National Astronomical Observatories, CAS, KIAA, Peking University, On behalf of the CSST Team, ISSI-BJ Workshop: Weak gravitational lensing studies from space missions, Beijing, 2019.11.05
2. [The Chinese Survey Space Telescope (a.k.a. the Chinese Space Station Telescope)](http://ilariacaiazzo.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/HuZhanSlides.pdf), Hu Zhan, NAOC & PKU, UV Club, Caltech 2021.09.22

In the 2nd link on slide 7 in the table of specifications:

> Wavelength 0.255-1 μm, 0.9-1.7 μm, **0.41-0.51 THz**

Near-Terahertz radio astronomy is a regular thing, ALMA's band 10 goes up to 0.95 THz for example

- [How does ALMA produce stable, mutually coherent ~THz local oscillators for all of their dishes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28666/7982)
- [Do circa 1 THz radio telescope front end amplifiers actually down convert before amplifying? At what frequency does amplification become untenable?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/48829/7982)
- [Highest frequency that's been imaged by a radio telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35975/7982)

and the famous images "of" supermassive black holes (M78* and Sgr A*) were made at about 0.23 THz. The Xuntian space telescope's range is between these.

- [What part of the EM spectrum was used in the black hole image?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30362/7982)
- [Why does the Event Horizon Telescope (EHT) not include telescopes from Africa, Asia or Australia?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30441/7982)

And I think the Sofia measurements were at about 2 THz:

- [this answer to *Is Sofia a radio telescope proper?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43398/7982)

**Question:** How will China's Xuntian (the [Chinese Survey Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xuntian)) use its Terahertz capability? THz Spectroscopy? Imaging? *Something else?*

Comment: in meta: [What is the best way to tag questions about Xuntian, the Chinese Survey Space Telescope?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/899/7982)

Comment: There's a brief description of the THz instrument on slide 22 of the second link; it appears to be devoted to spectroscopy.

Comment: @PeterErwin I guess it would be hard to imagine a radio receiver not having spectroscopic capability (unless it's a bolometer) but can we find out if it's sort-of the equivalent of a single slit spectrometer, or more of imaging system (like the array of antennas described in the linked Sofia question or [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16237/7982))?